# vulkan.hpp bindings generate WinAPI errors

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, vulkan

I reinstalled Visual Studio 2019 and installed Vulkan SDK (the latest version) for Windows but while there are no problems with `vulkan.h`, `vulkan.hpp` generates `identifier HMODULE is undefined` error right after including it.

This is the snippet with error:

```
#if defined(__linux__) || defined(__APPLE__)
    void *m_library;
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    HMODULE m_library;
#else
#error unsupported platform
#endif
```

Am I supposed to define something before including it or what? In [the official repo](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Hpp) of Khronos Group it is stated that all I need is visual studio 2015 or newer. I'm also getting 2 compiler errors related to `LoadLibrary` and `FreeLibrary` functions which msvc can't seem to find too.

Comment: @AlexF Well yes, but not directly. After digging into the issue I found that there is #ifdef VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR inside vulkan.h header. Turns out I just had to define it and everything works fine now

Comment: This comment can be posted as an answer to help people with the same questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, The platform-specific surface creation functions need be enabled using defines. For Windows you need to define `VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR` in your project’s windows build configuration